# How to cache query result into cache memory of server side where data will be cached by it's search term in entity framework core?

Tags: .net-core, caching, entity-framework-core

```cs
public bool IsApprovalFlowRequired(Type commandType, Type? responseType)
{
    CommandQuery? command = null;
    try
    {
        command = _dbContext.CommandQueries
            .Include(x => x.CommandApprovalFlowConfiguration)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ApprovalFlowConfiguration)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ApprovalFlowConfigurationDetails)
            .Where(x =>
                        x.FullName == commandType.FullName
                        &&
                        x.ResponseFullName == (responseType == null ? null : responseType.FullName)
                    )
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (command == null) return false;

    return command?.CommandApprovalFlowConfiguration?.ApprovalFlowConfiguration?.ApprovalFlowConfigurationDetails?.Count > 0;
}
```

In this project I have this query where I check if the command executed has approval flow required or not?
But every time checking the configuration from database is costly as it is call before every command execution. I have many more database calls like this method as well.

Is there any way to implement database caching which will automatically cache the data according to my LINQ query & is conditional parameter values?

Note: I need a solution which caches the data results automatically and it can be configured globally/manually in a Repository pattern.

Currently I tried to cache it manually for every DB requests. But I want to make the caching feature global. Where all DB query results will be cached by configuration just like `OutputCache` system of asp.net core web api.

Comment: The query is *very* inefficient. You pull a lot of data into memory and in the end you only need a count. Change the LINQ query into something like `_dbContext.CommandQueries.CommandApprovalFlowConfiguration.ApprovalFlowConfiguration.ApprovalFlowConfigurationDetails.Any()` and the database will only return a bool value.

Comment: Yes, query is inefficient. Thanks for your suggestions. But this is placed as just an example. I need to know a proper way of caching data results from DbContext data results. Which will be cached just like OutputCache system of asp.net core web api.

Comment: Even if you can cache, but how do you plan to invalidate cache?

Comment: If I can cache, then I think there will also be some ways to invalidate it as well. But for now I need to know the way how can I implement it.

Comment: Check this library [EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor](https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor). I'm pretty sure there are several similar analogues in github.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great solution for my issue. But is there any official library developed by Microsoft?